# Leaflet - select layer based on item from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some code to generate a simple drop down menu:

```
<select id="menu" onchange="updateOptions(this)">
    <option value="option1" data-path="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2" data-path="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3" data-path="option3">option3</option>
</select><br>
```

What I'd like to do is to have the selected option (which points to a declared Leaflet tilelayer) be added to the Leaflet map as a layer. Code for function and variables below:

```
var option1 = L.tileLayer('mapelements/basestructure/option1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
    option2= L.tileLayer('mapelements/basestructure/option2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
    option3= L.tileLayer('mapelements/basestructure/option3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')

var menufaults = document.getElementById("menu");

function updateFaults(menufaults) {
     map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    });
    var menuoption1 = menufaults.options[menufaults.selectedIndex].value;
    map.addLayer(menuoption1);
    };
```

The variable menuoption1 is pulling the correct option value from the menu, but the map.addLayer function doesn't like that as input. I get an 'provided object is not a layer' error. Is there a way to pass the 'option value' to the function so that it corresponds to the tile layer already declared as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object to map each options' value to a layer, here is an example:

```
const layersMap = { option1, option2, option3 };
```

And then do:

```
map.addLayer(layersMap[menuoption1]);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is the working solution I have been using. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to write it so that I didn't have to generate another object to map menu options to variables...